# Automapper not mapping on ICollection

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

My automapper configuration

```
   public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
          
            CreateMap<SampleParameter, SampleParameterModel>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<SampleResult, SampleResultModel>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<Sampling, SamplingModel>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<User, UserModel>().ReverseMap();
        }
```

This won't map the ICollection to ICollection in the object Sampling & SamplingModel

```
 public class Sampling : BaseEntity
    {
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SampleResult> SampleResults {get;set;}
    }

public class SamplingModel : BaseModel
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public LocationModel Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SampleResultModel> SampleResults { get; set; }

}

  public IActionResult SamplingsByFilter([FromBody] SamplingHeaderFilterModel filter)
        {
            var samplings = samplingService.GetSamplingsByFilter(filter).Include("SampleResults").AsQueryable();
            var pagedResult = PageResult(samplings, e => this.mapper.Map<Sampling, SamplingModel>(e), new UrlQueryOptions(new QueryCollection()));
            return pagedResult;
        }
```

Exception

## Error: Error mapping types.

```
Mapping types:
Sampling -> SamplingModel
BLD.Legionella.Domain.Entities.Sampling -> BLD.Legionella.Domain.Models.SamplingModel

Type Map configuration:
Sampling -> SamplingModel
BLD.Legionella.Domain.Entities.Sampling -> BLD.Legionella.Domain.Models.SamplingModel

Destination Member:
**SampleResults**
```

at lambda_method(Closure , Sampling , SamplingModel , ResolutionContext )
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()

Comment: Works on my internet: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lSBlSR

Comment: Ok i found my problem there was a cast exception on in the child object. Thx for the working example. I took me on the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem there was a cast exception on in the child object.
The exception was not clear so difficult to find where the problem was

Comment: Surely `exception.ToString()` has all the relevant information.